# A confusion with while loop

Tags: while-loop

```
    ConfirmationforNewDeviceName= str(input("Please insert 'Yes' or 'No' :"))
    while (ConfirmationforNewDeviceName != "Yes" or 
        ConfirmationforNewDeviceName != "yes" or
        ConfirmationforNewDeviceName != "No" or
        ConfirmationforNewDeviceName != "no"):
        ConfirmationforNewDeviceName= str(input("Please insert 'Yes' or 'No' :"))
```

This is my program in Python 3 . I want that the loop end only if I get Yes, yes, No, or no of string in line 1 otherwise it continue to run. But in given program i have created the loop didn't end whatever i write. It continue to show the "Please insert 'Yes' or 'No' :" of the line 7. Please help me to overcome this.

Comment: Try switching your "OR"s to "AND"s -- you want it to continue if all of those are not true.

Comment: Please work on your fundamentals a bit more. You need to understand what you are trying to accomplish, currently you are making things more complicated than they are.

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping out. I get it last night asking from my classmate. My program is now running good. Thank to all very much

Answer (score 0):

You need `and`s, not `or`s.

If `ConfirmationforNewDeviceName` is `"yes"`, think about this:

```
"yes" != "Yes" or "yes" != "yes"
```

That evaluates to `True or False`, which evaluates to `True`. On the other hand:

```
"yes" != "Yes" and "yes" != "yes"
```

evaluates to `True and False`, which evaluates to `False` as expected.

Comment: Thanks Buddy for helping me out